# how to align a sidebar to the right with css?

Tags: html, css

Am trying to make a simple sidebar, I made this code till now , and I didn't figure out how to make it float to the right , am so confused.

here is a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7bx0v1s/)

```css
._sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 3rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  background-image: initial;
  background-position-x: initial;
  background-position-y: initial;
  background-size: initial;
  background-repeat-x: initial;
  background-repeat-y: initial;
  background-attachment: initial;
  background-origin: initial;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
  background-clip: content-box;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
section {
  outline: 0;
  width: 300px;
  outline-color: initial;
  outline-style: initial;
  outline-width: 0px;
}
aside,
section,
div {
  display: block;
}
body {
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  font: normal 1em/1.7"Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
._sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 10px;
}
._sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}
._sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  min-height: 2rem;
  background: #d2d2d2;
  background-image: initial;
  background-position-x: initial;
  background-position-y: initial;
  background-size: initial;
  background-repeat-x: initial;
  background-repeat-y: initial;
  background-attachment: initial;
  background-origin: initial;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 3px;
  border-right-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 3px;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
._list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 18rem;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 #e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<section class="_sidebar">
  <div role="navigation" class="_list">

    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code is kind of awkward, but if you just want to move this to the right, simply change `left:0` to `right:0`

```css
  ._sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 3rem;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    background-image: initial;
    background-position-x: initial;
    background-position-y: initial;
    background-size: initial;
    background-repeat-x: initial;
    background-repeat-y: initial;
    background-attachment: initial;
    background-origin: initial;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
    background-clip: content-box;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
  }
  
  section {
    outline: 0;
    width: 300px;
    outline-color: initial;
    outline-style: initial;
    outline-width: 0px;
  }
  
  aside,
  section,
  div {
    display: block;
  }
  
  body {
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    font: normal 1em/1.7 "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.7;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  
  ._sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 10px;
  }
  
  ._sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
  }
  
  ._sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    min-height: 2rem;
    background: #d2d2d2;
    background-image: initial;
    background-position-x: initial;
    background-position-y: initial;
    background-size: initial;
    background-repeat-x: initial;
    background-repeat-y: initial;
    background-attachment: initial;
    background-origin: initial;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-right-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  ._list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 18rem;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 #e3e3e3;
  }
```

```html
<section class="_sidebar">
  <div role="navigation" class="_list">

    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <br>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your `._sidebar`, just change the property:

```
left:0;
```

to:

```
right:0;
```

You have used absolute positioning, so this will work.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arnavb11/xsomc84k/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
position : absolute;
```

And replace it with float:right:

```
._sidebar{
    float: right;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    background-image: initial;
    background-position-x: initial;
    background-position-y: initial;
    background-size: initial;
    background-repeat-x: initial;
    background-repeat-y: initial;
    background-attachment: initial;
    background-origin: initial;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
    background-clip: content-box;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `position:absoulte` and add `float:right` at `._sidebar` selector,

Answer (score 0):

you can put right 0px and remove left 0px in _sidebar

see the code

```
._sidebar {

    right: 0;

}
```